# pandas: pandas.DataFrame.describe returns information on only one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, kaggle

For a certain Kaggle dataset (rules prohibit me from sharing the data here, but is readily accessible [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predicting-red-hat-business-value/data)),

```
import pandas
df_train = pandas.read_csv(
    "01 - Data/act_train.csv.zip"
)
df_train.describe()
```

I get:

```
>>> df_train.describe()
            outcome
count  2.197291e+06
mean   4.439544e-01
std    4.968491e-01
min    0.000000e+00
25%    0.000000e+00
50%    0.000000e+00
75%    1.000000e+00
max    1.000000e+00
```

whereas for the same dataset `df_train.columns` gives me:

```
>>> df_train.columns
Index(['people_id', 'activity_id', 'date', 'activity_category', 'char_1',
       'char_2', 'char_3', 'char_4', 'char_5', 'char_6', 'char_7', 'char_8',
       'char_9', 'char_10', 'outcome'],
      dtype='object')
```

and `df_train.dtypes` gives me:

```
>>> df_train.dtypes
people_id            object
activity_id          object
date                 object
activity_category    object
char_1               object
char_2               object
char_3               object
char_4               object
char_5               object
char_6               object
char_7               object
char_8               object
char_9               object
char_10              object
outcome               int64
dtype: object
```

Am I missing some reason why pandas only `describe`s one column in the dataset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `describe` only works on numeric dtype columns. Add a keyword-argument `include='all'`. [From the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

> If include is the string ‘all’, the output column-set will match the
>   input one.

To clarify, the default arguments to `describe` are `include=None, exclude=None`. The behavior that results is:

> None to both (default). The result will include only numeric-typed
>   columns or, if none are, only categorical columns.

Also, from the **Notes** section:

> The output DataFrame index depends on the requested dtypes:
>
> For numeric dtypes, it will include: count, mean, std, min, max, and
>   lower, 50, and upper percentiles.
>
> For object dtypes (e.g. timestamps or strings), the index will include
>   the count, unique, most common, and frequency of the most common.
>   Timestamps also include the first and last items.

Comment: But `include='all'` is the default if all the columns in the dataset are objects (strings)?

Comment: Then the question changes to -- are `object` columns interpreted as categorical columns by pandas in the latter case?

Comment: @tchakravarty Yes, object dtype columns are interpreted as categorical.

Comment: Can you include some documentation that mentions that `object` types are interpreted as `categorical` types?

Comment: @tchakravarty Yes, it's included in my final edit. i.e. `For object dtypes (e.g. timestamps or strings), the index will include the count, unique, most common, and frequency of the most common`

Comment: No, I was referring to your claim that `object` columns are interpreted as `categorical` as they are distinct types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122082/discussion-between-juanpa-arrivillaga-and-tchakravarty).

Answer (score 0):

try the follwing code

```
import pandas
df_train = pandas.read_csv(
    "01 - Data/act_train.csv.zip"
)

def describe_categorical(df_train):
    from Ipython.display import display, HTML
    display (HTML(df_train[df_train.columns[df_train.dtypes=="object"]].describe().to_html()))

describe_categorical(df_train)
```